# How to get a value from a Pandas DataFrame and not the index and object type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following DataFrame

```
Letter    Number
A          1
B          2
C          3
D          4
```

Which can be obtained through the following code

```
import pandas as pd

letters = pd.Series(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
numbers = pd.Series((1, 2, 3, 4))
keys = ('Letters', 'Numbers')
df = pd.concat((letters, numbers), axis=1, keys=keys)
```

Now I want to get the value C from the column Letters.

The command line

```
df[df.Letters=='C'].Letters
```

will return

```
2    C
Name: Letters, dtype: object
```

How can I get only the value C and not the whole two line output?

Comment: On an unrelated note, there's a nicer way to contruct your DataFrame :```pd.DataFrame({'Letters': letters, 'Numbers': numbers})```

Answer (score 247, accepted):

```
df[df.Letters=='C'].Letters.item()
```

This returns the first element in the Index/Series returned from that selection. In this case, the value is always the first element.

**EDIT:**

Or you can run a loc() and access the first element that way. This was shorter and is the way I have implemented it in the past.

- [Pandas Index doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.item.html?highlight=item#pandas.Index.item)
- [Pandas Series doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html?highlight=item#pandas.Series.item)

Comment: I love this method, however I'm getting the warning: `FutureWarning: "item" has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version`

Comment: @AlexG: you can use this instead: `df[df.Letters=='C'].Letters.iloc[0]`. It produces the first element (which is also the unique) in the result series.

Comment: using loc[:1] still shows index next to the value :(

Comment: @AlexG and @Sonic Soul : try using `df[df.Letters=='C'].Letters.squeeze()` instead. This works the same way. :)

Answer (score 94):

Use the `values` attribute to return the values as a np array and then use `[0]` to get the first value:

```
In [4]:
df.loc[df.Letters=='C','Letters'].values[0]

Out[4]:
'C'
```

**EDIT**

I personally prefer to access the columns using subscript operators:

```
df.loc[df['Letters'] == 'C', 'Letters'].values[0]
```

This avoids issues where the column names can have spaces or dashes `-` which mean that accessing using `.`.

Comment: It's really inconsequential, but in your selection you access the column 'Letters' using the dot notation; df.loc[df.Letters=='C']. If there are spaces in your column names, you should probably be using converters to strip those out, like you would if importing from a CSV or Excel file.

Comment: @thomas-ato I'll update my answer but I disagree with modding the columns as an additional step unless that is necessary, in this case I agree it makes no difference

Comment: @EdChum.. In this scenarion : how can we handle error: "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `loc` with the index and column labels.

```py
df.loc[2, 'Letters']
# 'C'
```

If you prefer the "Numbers" column as reference, you can set it as index.

```py
df.set_index('Numbers').loc[3, 'Letters']
```

I find this cleaner as it does not need the `[0]` or `.item()`.

Comment: This doesn't address the particular issue. If the index is unknown, your code doesn't help.

Comment: The second version (setting one column to index) does apply in that case. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
values = list(x for x in dataset["column name"])

>>> values[0]
'item_0'
```

edit:

actually, you can just index the dataset like any old array.

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
first_value = dataset["column name"][0]

>>> print(first_value)
'item_0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good option is to turn your single line DataFrame into a Series first, then index that:

```
df[df.Letters=='C'].squeeze()['Letters']
```